# Media player with circular ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I wanna connect my media player to the progress bar Here is my code :

```
var media55 :MediaPlayer
var progressBar55 :ProgressBar

        progressBar55=findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
        media55 = MediaPlayer()
        media55.setDataSource("SONG URL HERE")
        media55.prepare()
```

**I wanna when I start media player the progress bar progress with the media player**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define Handler in class scope.

```
private val handler = Handler()
```

Then set your ProgressBar max value to duration of the MediaPlayer data source.

```
progressBar55.max = media55.duration
```

Finally add a Runnable object to set progress on your ProgressBar every X milliseconds.

```
val interval: Long = 1000
val statusChecker = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        progressBar.progress = media.currentPosition
        handler.postDelayed(this, interval)
    }
}
```

When you run your audio you should call `statusChecker.run()` to start updating porgress, and when you are done remove Handler callbacks by calling `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`

Answer (score 0):

I hope Its Hepls You

> Using Handler

```
private lateinit var mHandler: Handler
private lateinit var mRunnable:Runnable
```

> Just Create Function For This

```
fun startedSong()
{
mRunnable = Runnable {
                // Do something here
    if(media55.isPlaying)
    {
       progressBar55.progress=media55.currentPosition
    }
}
                // Schedule the task to repeat after 1 second
                mHandler.postDelayed(
                        mRunnable, // Runnable
                        1000 // Delay in milliseconds
                )
}
```

> Call This Function In Your Code

```
    progressBar55=findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
    media55 = MediaPlayer()
    media55.setDataSource("SONG URL HERE")
    media55.prepare()
    progressBar55.max=media55.duration
    mHandler = Handler()
    startedSong()
```